# How to show button only the time between 9am to 5pm in react js or javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time

Let's say I have a button that should display only on the particular time period(9am to 5pm), otherwise the button should not display.

Comment: check the time ... hide/display button as appropiate

Comment: what is the issue here? why you giving negative score?

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement is only entered if the time is between 9:00 and 17:00 (5pm).

```js
const date = new Date();
const hours = date.getHours();

if (hours >= 9 && hours <= 16) {
    // add code to show button
}
```